# Every link is working fine except the menu links saying "There has been an error..." in magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, error

I have transferred the magento files from live server to localhost.
Every thing is working fine but when I am clicking to any menu links,it gives an error saying
"There has been an issue..."

I am using magento 1.8

Please look at this issue and provide me any hint..
Thanks in advance.

Below is the error log file

```
a:5:{i:0;s:163:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in C:\xampp\htdocs\baby_demo\app\code\local\Magentothem\Layerednavigationajax\controllers\CategoryController.php, line 15";i:1;s:1013:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\baby_demo\lib\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)

**#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\baby_demo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1246): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; char...')

**#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\baby_demo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()

**#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\baby_demo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(202): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse()

**#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\baby_demo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

**#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\baby_demo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

**#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\baby_demo\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

******#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\baby_demo\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Comment: how can we look at the issue?

Comment: I have added the error..Please check this.

Comment: I've added an answer. See if it fits.

Comment: these did not solved my issue..

Comment: I have marked..can u please tell me the next issue

Comment: Create new question,don't put question  in answer @priti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the file `Magentothem\Layerednavigationajax\controllers\CategoryController.php`.
Most probably you have a space or an other character before the `<?php` opening tag or after the closing tag `?>`. In fact remove completely the closing tag at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Yes this issue is solved..

but now below the product name there is something wrritten as "getRatingSummary()): ?>"

What is the issue???